# HTML Agility Pack Question (Attempting to parse string from source)

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am attempting to use the Agility pack to parse certain bits of info from various pages. I am kind of worried that using this might be overkill for what I need, if that is case feel free to let me know. Anyway, I am attempting to parse a page from motley fool to get the name of a company based on the ticker. I will be parsing several pages to get stock info in a similar way.

The HTML that I want to parse looks like:

```
<h1 class="subHead"> 
    Microsoft Corp <span>(NASDAQ:MSFT)</span>
</h1>
```

Also, the page I want to parse is: http://caps.fool.com/Ticker/MSFT.aspx

So, I guess my question is how do I simply get the Microsoft Corp from the html and should I even be using the agility pack to do things like this?

**Edit:** Current code

```
public String getStockName(String ticker)
{
    String text ="";
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://caps.fool.com/Ticker/" + ticker + ".aspx");

    var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/h1[@class='subHead']");
    text = node.FirstChild.InnerText.Trim();
    return text;
}
```

Comment: I find the HTML Agility Pack is great for situations like this - i.e. where there is no data source provided, but you would still like to parse 3rd-party data for some reason. I've done something quite similar to what you're working on in the past. Next step is to parse out the price, daily change etc. :)

Comment: @C.McAtackney Thanks! Yep, this one is just the start, but I think once I get my feet wet it will not be as rough. I appreciate you letting me know that I am on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would give you a list of all stock names, for your sample Html just of Microsoft:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("test.html");

var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h1[@class='subHead']");
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    string text = node.FirstChild.InnerText; //output: "Microsoft Corp"
    string textAll = node.InnerText; //output: "Microsoft Corp (NASDAQ:MSFT)"
}
```

**Edit** based on updated question - this should work for you:

```
string text = "";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

string url = string.Format("http://caps.fool.com/Ticker/{0}.aspx", ticker);
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);

var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h1[@class='subHead']");
text = node.FirstChild.InnerText.Trim();
return text;
```

Comment: @broken Thanks! I appreciate the help. IF you don't mind, I am having one other small issue that I described at the bottom of my edit and I would appreciate any help you might have on that issue. Have a great day!

Comment: @BrokenGlass thank you again! I am working with your updated code, but still getting an error. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." It is happening at the node...Trim(). Is it possible that the Select node is not finding anything?

Comment: @PFranchise: This code works for me, tested with `ticker = "MSFT"` - just tried again using `AAPL` and works fine too - are you sure you are using *exactly* this code?

Comment: @PFranchise: You are missing a backslash in your updated code: it should be `var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h1[@class='subHead']");` - that's most likely your problem

Comment: @BrokenGlass aha! All works! thank you very much for the awesome help. I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Use an xpath expression to select the element then pickup the text.

```
 foreach (var element in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h1[@clsss='subHead']/span"))
 {
    Console.WriteLine (element.InnerText);
 }
```